# How to pass a variable from one jsp to another?

Tags: jsp, struts1

Environment : Struts 1.3.10

I have 2 links which will open same jsp (viewEmployee.jsp).
Here based on link pressed (rejected / accepted) employees info need to be displayed.

```
<ul>

 <li> <html:link page="/viewEmployee.jsp" > Rejected Employees</html:link> </li>
 <li> <html:link page="/viewEmployee.jsp" > Accepted Employees</html:link> </li>

</ul>
```

how to use param to identify which link is clicked so corresponding employee list will be displayed

Comment: The whole idea of an MVC framework like Struts is to NEVER directly access a view. Always go through a controller, which then dispatches to the right view. Just use two different URLs, to two different actions (or methods of an action). Also, Struts 1 is an officially abandoned project, and it is abandoned for years now. Why do you still use that?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. will go for dispatch action.